# Create a custom list in sharepoint via Visual Studio

Tags: sharepoint

I've created a customlist in **Visual Studio 2013** and deployed the same in the **SharePoint 2013** server. Its working fine and is showing in the "Site Settings -> Site Features" area of my sharepoint site. This will allow the user to activate/deactivate it. But, my site may be a big one in size and I want to create a lot of lists via VisualStudio. So, Is it possible to avoid listing it in "Site Features" area ? This is not listing for lists available in  SharePoint, when we add it via UI?

Answer (score 1):

What you see in Site Features section is sharepoint feature not list it self. You can include any number of lists in one feature.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can we map multiple lists to a single feature ?

Comment: In visual studio open "Features" folder in project explorer and double click on feature which is present there. You will get to feature designer where you can change what items will be included in feature.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the "Is Hidden" to true, which have hidden the list from listing in "Site Features" section.

Comment: It is not what i meant, but ok...
You can have only one feature for all lists.
Mark answer if it helped you. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I want to avoid the listing of feature option for all the custom lists in the Site Features section. If I didn't get that hidden feature, I would have done this. I don't know if this is a correct method. Thanks a lot for your response.